# How to add/edit project resources from within the code in C#?

Tags: c#, string, image, resources, resourcedictionary

I want to add or edit my C# project resources from within the code. For example I have a string called *myString* in project resources. Now I want to change the value of this string:

```
MyProject.Properties.Resources.myString = "NewStringValue";
```

But the compiler gives an error that this property is read only. I also want to add an image by browsing the image and adding it to the project resources.
Any idea how I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am using Windows Form.

Comment: Do you want to update value inside resource file ?

Comment: The property mystring you have is an application property, in the settings change it to user and then you will be able to edit it.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. The project resources are loaded at compile time and cannot be modified at run-time, then there would be no performance benifits :P. Resources can be loaded in memory and used in the project, why do you want to do this via the Project resources? Maybe you can load all the resources you might need at compile time and decide run-time which ones to use.

Comment: I have multiple forms in my project, each form has a picture box, I want to give the user the option to browse a jpeg file and upload it. Every picture box in all the forms has to be able to access that jpeg image. Also that jpeg should be the default picture box image so that on the next application run the uploaded image should appear in the picture box.

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Properties -> Resources -> open the resx file -> select images. There you can see the images in your project.
You can add new images by dragging them into that area.
[image]

This code will store the chosen images and load the last stored image at startup.
You may have to make it Observable or do something to make all the PictureBoxes update their image.

```
public class DefaultPicture
{
    private static string settings = "picture.settings";

    private System.Drawing.Bitmap image = new Bitmap(settings);

    public Bitmap Image
    {
        get
        {
            return this.image;
        }
        set
        {
            this.image = value;
            this.image.Save(settings);
        }
    }
}
```